# Mocking import in function decorator definition

Tags: python, mocking, python-decorators

I'm unable to figure out where exactly this function is being looked up, so I don't know the path to provide to the patch decorator.

```
<file b.py>

from a import function_to_mock

def deco(*args, **kwargs):
    user = kwargs['user']
    ...some db access, user validation...

    def outer(func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def inner(*args, *kwargs):
            bool = function_to_mock(args[0])

            if bool:
                # inject variable from outermost level into decorated function
                kwargs['user'] = user  
                return func(*args, **kwargs)
            else:
                raise ValueError('error...')

        return inner
    return outer
```

Testing code:

```
def test_deco(self):
    with patch('path.to.b.function_to_mock', lambda x: self.pilot):
        @deco(roles=[UserRole.Pilot], getter=some_function)
        def func(request, **kwargs):
            print('func kwargs %s' % kwargs)
            ...assertions...

    func({'some': '4'})
```

I've tried to patch both 'path.to.a.function_to_mock' and 'path.to.b.function_to_mock' but neither seem to be working. What is the correct path? Alternatively, is there a better way to test the decorator function?

Comment: Could you give a less abstract example? That decorator seems weird. If you want it to be easier to test, don't close over `function_to_mock`, refactor to make it an explicit parameter at some level.

Comment: Given your import in `b.py`, you want `path.to.b.function_to_mock` (the `path.to.a.function_to_mock` version would make sense if in `b` you used `import a ` and `a.function_to_mock(args[0])`). Now as to why it doesn't  work with `path.to.b.function_to_mock` , I do suspect it _might_ have something to do with the closure but I may be plain wrong too.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've edited the code to hopefully make it less abstract. The issue is that I need args[0] from the decorated function before I can call `function_to_mock`, so it's difficult to make it explicit.